# From where the Stored Procedure file will be called when using @filename in SQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL statement: `SELECT sys_context('userenv','db_name') FROM dual;`. I stored it inside a SQL file called `db.sql` in C:

Now, I can run this file:

> @C:\db.sql

I know we can invoke the file just as @db, but, when I try it, I get this error:

```
SQL> @db
SP2-0310: unable to open file "db.sql"
```

So, where should I place the file? I read here http://docs.oracle.com/html/B12033_01/sqlplus.htm that I have to edit some variable names like SQLPATH. Where should I edit this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself :) here sharing this...

Always these files will be looked in Bin of your Oracle Client. Most user create ORACLE_HOME environmental variable at time of installation and the files will be looked in ORACLE_HOME\Bin

1. So create a environmental variable if not present already pointing
   to [driver/folder_installed]/product/{version}/client
2. Place the files in bin

that's all enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

SQLPATH seems like an environment variable.
RClick on your MyComputer. Go to "Advanced System Settings". Under "Advanced" Tabs click on "Environment Variables..." and there you can set the SQLPATH under your system variables if you have admin rights.

Comment: straight from the link I gave " SQL*Plus searches the path(s) specified by the ORAENV environment variable SQLPATH" probably this will be inside Oracle Server

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, when you run sqlplus it will first look in the same location where sqlplus was run from - so I just edit my sqlplus shortcut "Start In" to be the folder where my scripts are located.